# Nested list traversing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

hello I am searching for this solution but couldn't find any

I want to convert below list

```
list1=[1,2,3,[4],5,[2,4]]

output=[1,2,3,4,5,2,4]
```

U got it with this code

```
list1=[1,2,3,[4],5,[2,4]]
list2=[]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if type(list1[i])!=int:
        for j in range(len(list1[i])):
            list2.append(list1[i][j])
    else:
        list2.append(list1[i])
print(list2)
```

Can anyone tell any other way to this without for loops and all

Comment: You could look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists) where similar topic has been discussed

Answer (score -1):

That could be a solution. Not the best one, but a solution :

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, [4], 5, [2, 4]]
l = []
for i in list1:
    if type(i) is int:
        l.append(i)
    elif type(i) is list:
        for a in i:
            l.append(a)
```

Better :

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, [4], 5, [2, 4]]
l = []
for i in list1:
    if type(i) is int:
        l.append(i)
    elif type(i) is list:
        l.extend(i)
```

Comment: This will only work if the nesting level is limited. What if `list1 = [1, [[[[2]]]]]`?

Comment: I dont why but isnt's working in jupyter notebook

Comment: i have to use list1 = [1, 2, 3, [4], 5, [2, 4]]
l = []
for i in list1:
    if type(i) is int:
        l.append(i)
    elif type(i) is not int:
        l.extend(i)
print(l)

Comment: is not int , its not checkin for list data type if i use is list